# What data GLSL takes?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

What data GLSL takes? For example I have a matrix 4x4, which is following kind:

```
float **matrix = new float*[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    matrix[i] = new matrix[4];
```

Can the GLSL to take this, as mat4x4?

Or, better to use following:

```
float *matrix = new float[16];
```

I haven't found this information in specification of GLSL 1.30(I have use particularly this version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should make use of `GLfloat` instead that float, since it's there exactly to represent GL data which is used by your program and the GPU.

Regarding your specific question [`glUniform`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) has many flavours used to send what you need. You have both

```
void glUniformMatrix2f(GLint location, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose, const GLfloat *value);
void glUniformMatrix4f(GLint location, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose, const GLfloat *value);
```

You can use them easily by passing the pointer to your data:

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(variable,"variable_name");
glUniformMatrix4f(location, 1, false, &matrix);
```

Comment: If the OP allocates `matrix` the second way, then there is no need to pass the address of the variable. GL expects a `GLfloat*` not `GLfloat**`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the first variant, because the 16 floats of the matrix data will be allocated in different memory areas. You store array of 4 pointers, each pointing to separate 4xfloat array. OpenGL expects data to be located sequentially, so either use the second variant or use struct/static 2d array:

```
GLfloat[4][4]
```

It may be convenient to use the existing library for that, fore example [gl matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_matrix.html)

Answer (score 3):

> What data GLSL takes? For example I have a matrix 4x4, which is following kind:
>
> ```
> float **matrix = new float*[4];
> for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
>     matrix[i] = new matrix[4];
> ```

That's not a 4×4 matrix. That's an array of pointers to arrays of 4 float elements.

> Can the GLSL to take this, as mat4x4?

No, because it's not a matrix.

A 4×4 matrix would be a region of contiguous memory that contains `4·4 = 16` values (floats if you will) of which you denote, that each n-tuple (n=4) of values forms a vector and the m-tuple (m=4) of vectors forms a matrix.

> Or, better to use following:
>
> ```
> float *matrix = new float[16];
> ```

That would be a contiguous region of memory holding 16 = 4·4 float values, which by denotion can be interpreted as a 4×4 matrix of floats. So yes, this can be interpreted by OpenGL / GLSL as a 4×4 matrix of floats `mat4`.

However if you make this part of some class don't use dynamic memory.

```
class foo {
    foo() { matrix = new float[16]; }
    float *matrix;
};
```

Is bad, because you create some unnecessary overhead. If the class is dynamically allocated (with `new`) that will trigger another dynamic memory allocation, which creates overhead. If the instances are on automatic memory (stack, i.e. no new), it also imposes unnecessary overhead.

```
class foo {
    foo() { … }
    float matrix[16];
};
```

is much better, because if the class instances are created with `new` that also covers the memory for the matrix. And if it's on automatic memory it completely avoids the overhead of dynamic allocation.